# Google App Engine Deploy - JSP Compilation Error

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsp, google-app-engine

I have a GAE Project which builds correctly without giving any error. At the time of deployment I am getting JSP compilation errors saying it is not able to find few GSON classes and javax.rs.ws classes. But I have below dependencies mentioned in the pom file. How can I fix this error? I recently converted this project (normal eclipse Java project which was deploying to GAE correctly)to maven project. Since then I am getting this issue.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
      <version>2.9</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.7</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Please find the error in eclipse below.

```
Preparing to deploy:
    Created staging directory at: '/tmp/appcfg3293637348520625850.tmp'
    Scanning for jsp files.
    Compiling jsp files.
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile the generated JSP java files.
```

Please find some of the detailed errors.

```
  symbol:   class GsonBuilder
  location: class goal_005fsuggestions_005flistall_jsp
/tmp/1470213274561-0/org/apache/jsp/admin/goal_005fsuggestions_005flistall_jsp.java:92: error: cannot find symbol
            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<GoalSuggestionEntity>>() {}.getType();
                                ^
  symbol:   class TypeToken
  location: class goal_005fsuggestions_005flistall_jsp
/tmp/1470213274561-0/org/apache/jsp/admin/goalcategories_005flistall_jsp.java:91: error: cannot find symbol
       Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
       ^
  symbol:   class Gson
  location: class goalcategories_005flistall_jsp
/tmp/1470213274561-0/org/apache/jsp/admin/goalcategories_005flistall_jsp.java:91: error: cannot find symbol
       Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                       ^
  symbol:   class GsonBuilder
  location: class goalcategories_005flistall_jsp
/tmp/1470213274561-0/org/apache/jsp/admin/goalcategories_005flistall_jsp.java:92: error: cannot find symbol
       Type listType = new TypeToken<List<GoalCategoryEntity>>() {}.getType();
                           ^
  symbol:   class TypeToken
  location: class goalcategories_005flistall_jsp
/tmp/1470213274561-0/org/apache/jsp/admin/goal_005flistall_jsp.java:89: error: cannot find symbol
       Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
       ^
  symbol:   class Gson
  location: class goal_005flistall_jsp
/tmp/1470213274561-0/org/apache/jsp/admin/goal_005flistall_jsp.java:89: error: cannot find symbol
       Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                       ^
  symbol:   class GsonBuilder
  location: class goal_005flistall_jsp
/tmp/1470213274561-0/org/apache/jsp/admin/goal_005flistall_jsp.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
       Type listType = new TypeToken<List<GoalEntity>>() {}.getType();
                           ^
  symbol:   class TypeToken
  location: class goal_005flistall_jsp
68 errors
```

Comment: have you tried `mvn clean gcloud:deploy`?

Comment: also, please add the error log

Comment: Hi, I added the errors in the question.

Comment: Tried the gcloud:deploy, but getting the NullPointerException. Not sure how to even debug this.  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:gcloud-maven-plugin:2.0.9.119.v20160801:deploy (default-cli) on project EverydayLearning: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.appengine:gcloud-maven-plugin:2.0.9.119.v20160801:deploy failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]

Comment: Take a look at this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/maven And please use the - E or - X flags to produce logs on the previous command as well.

Comment: Also try reinstalling your dependencies with mvn clean install

Comment: Tried this, I am getting error -- [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:gcloud-maven-plugin:2.0.9.119.v20160801:deploy (default-cli) on project EverydayLearning: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.appengine:gcloud-maven-plugin:2.0.9.119.v20160801:deploy failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:gcloud-maven-plugin:2.0.9.119.v20160801:deploy (default-cli) on project EverydayLearning: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.appengine:gcloud-maven-

Comment: Please use `mvn -V` and look for the java version in the first few lines, and check to see if it matches the one in your `pom.xml` file at the `maven-compiler-plugin`'s source and target part to see if they match. It would really help if you also updated your question with these infos.